# clustering approaches: binary data

Tags: clustering

I am investigating clinical outcomes following an injury. I have 8 different outcomes, all binary, and there is correlation between them with different subjects have combinations of different outcomes. I have done a PCA of the variables, with loading plot showing grouping of different outcome variables.

I was wanting to examine with a clustering-type approach to assess if there are clusters of patients with certain combination of outcomes. I can then investigate what the biological signatures of these clusters are. I was wondering what clustering approach people on the forum would take. It is 8 binary variables with no continuous variables. All 8 are different outcomes. I mainly work on R.

Many thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard approaches would be any distance-based clustering (such as complete or average linkage or partitioning around medoids) using an appropriate distance measure. The standard distances would be simple matching and Jaccard (R-function `daisy` with `metric="gower"` and `type` `"asymm"` or `"symm"`); there are some more in the literature, but one of these two makes sense in many applications. Jaccard (`"asymm"`) is the method of choice if joint presences (1) are meaningful but joint absences (0) are not; if 0 and 1 should be treated symmetrically, simple matching (`"symm"`) is better. Alternatively, one could fit a latent class mixture model assuming local independence within clusters (R-package `poLCA`).

I'd absolutely plot a [binary heatmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73619453/plot-a-heatmap-for-binary-categorical-variables-in-r) to get some feel for what is going on before deciding what clustering method(s) to take (note however that what is seen from this depends on the order of observations, and a standard approach for ordering them is hierarchical clustering, so this may already involve clustering).